# What to dress in Skype interview with foreign company

Tags: interviewing, czech-republic

I have recently applied for a job in the foreign country(Czech Republic) as a Junior Developer. Today I was contacted, that I have passed initial screening and there will be skype interview soon.

This will be my first interview over skype. I have read some tips on skype interviews recommending to dress formal, is it valid for IT sector?

I am completely unfamiliar with the Czech Republic culture, if I take my country(somewhere in Central Asia) as example I would most probably dressed casual.

Comment: Solid white or blue shirt and khakhis. You cannot go wrong with it. No need to suit up and don't risk with a tee shirt.

Comment: @PagMax No need for the khakis, go pantsless if you want. Just stay seated.

Comment: @NuclearWang haha..yes I thought about that but what if he has to get up to pick up a file or something or just answer the door bell ! It is not worth the risk!

Comment: Dress as you would if you were actually face to face.

Comment: @MisterPositive the problem is that I am not really familiar with the European culture

Comment: Being over dressed can almost never hurt you.  Its not about European culture anyway, its about the companies culture.

Comment: A good solution for the exact situation you describe is a *tidy* (ideally "expensive") check shirt.  Those kind of "fairly expensive" check shirts they sell at, for example, upmarket sporting good stores for hunters, etc.

Comment: @hatik you should mention the product sector.  So, games, apps, enterprise software, mathematical/scientific. social media, .. etc.  Please tell us!

Comment: @Fattie I do not have detailed information, it will be provided during interview

Comment: good luck anyway, @Hatik !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you researched the company? How formal are they? Are they corporate or have a tech culture? Take a look at photos of the team.

If they wear suits and ties, wear a suit and tie. If they wear t-shirts and jeans, wear something a bit more formal like a dress shirt without a tie or a nice polo shirt.

You always want to be a tad on the formal side, but not overdressed. It shows you're serious about your role, and that you researched their culture. Suit and tie to every interview regardless of the role and company often means you have not done your research.

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about company, most information will be provided during interview, this is what I was told. Now I think I should inquire much more from the 'middleman', thanks for advice

Comment: @Hatik look them up on linkedin and look at there website

Answer (score 3):

You're going to attend an interview, whether online, or in person. Dress formally.

Additionally, make sure that the interviewer can't see something in the background that will embarrass you. Clean up your room, and remove as much clutter as possible from the scene, such that you make a good impression.

Comment: I'd emphasise on how, in a skype interview, the background is probably more important than how you dress. There must be no distractions (visual or audio), lighting must be good and you should be comfortable spending a while working there (have a pen and paper at hand and water if you're gonna be thirsty).

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will not be having interview at my place, it will be held in the middleman's office.

Comment: **background** is a GREAT tip.  Also, go PEE before it begins.

Comment: I never dressed formally for a skype interview. At most, a shirt, no tshirts.